# How to specify lazy-init in the component-scan element?

Tags: java, spring, lazy-initialization

In an inherited java application, there are many java classes initialized by the @component annotation.

When attempting to run the application, the initialization takes a lot of time (>1 minute). How do I minimize this?

1. I tried using default-lazy-init="true" - This did not help in reducing the initialization time.
2. @Lazy annotation may be added to the added - There are too many classes & manually adding this annotation to all of them is not something I wish to do. More importantly, one of the packages is common, & I am not aware of the implications of lazy loading of the classes for other applications.

In the spring xml, there are three component-scans

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.java.package1" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.java.package2" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.java.package3" />
```

Is there some way to write one or two lines of code to initialize the @Component annotated classes in a lazy-loading fashion?

Better yet, is there anything else that can be done to decrease the initialization time?

Comment: you should first measure what takes so much time. My wild guess is that instantiating components is not the problem. Rather, accessing the disk, reading many jar files, opening database connections is what takes time.

Comment: I check the logs when the application gets initialized. The DB connections do not take too long as compared to the bean initialization.